# Showing that a formula is inconsistent.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $L$ be a first-order language with the predicate symbol $P$, and let $x,y$ be variables in $L$.

I want to show that

$$\forall x\neg\big(P(x) \rightarrow \forall yP(y)\big)$$

is inconsistent (I mean that the set of that sentence is inconsistent.

I am using Enderton's A Mathematical Introduction to Logic. I am not allowed to use the completeness theorem.
If a set of sentences $\Gamma$ is inconsistent it means that there exists a sentence $\sigma$ such that $\Gamma\vdash\sigma$ and $\Gamma\vdash\neg\sigma$.

Should I try to find such a $\sigma$ ?

I am not allowed to use the completeness theorem.

Comment: Can you use the fact that a set is consistent if and only if it has a model?

Comment: Is that theorem in Enderton's book?

Comment: There is no introduction to logic book it isn't in, it is the Completeness Theorem. But Enderton at this stage may want a syntactic argument.

Comment: Ahh, yes I remember now. Sorry, I should have included in the question that I am not allowed to use the completeness theorem.

Comment: Note that the sentence is equivalent to $$\forall x\Big(P(x)\land\exists y\big(\neg P(y)\big)\Big)\;.$$ I don’t know the details of Enderton’s approach, but I suspect that something like $\sigma=\forall x\big(P(x)\big)$ would work.

Comment: Alternatively one can prove that $\{\varphi\}$ is inconsistent by showing $\vdash\neg\varphi$. In this case $\neg\varphi$ happens to be the [Drinker paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox).

Comment: That's actually my true goal, I was given the hint that I should show that {$/phi$} is inconsistent. I also noticed that it's the Drinker paradox but don't really know what to do.

Comment: Something I generally struggle with is finding formal proofs of formulas with negation and constants because the axioms do not specifically mention them, so creativity is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that the formula :

> $∀x¬(P(x) → ∀yP(y))$

is *inconsistent* **iff** it is *unsatisfiable* (by the **Completeness Th**) **iff** its negation is *valid*.

In order to show the validity of :

> $¬∀x¬(P(x) → ∀yP(y))$ we have to consider the equivalent formula : $\exists x (¬P(x) \lor ∀yP(y))$.

According to the semantical specifications of :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA88) (2nd ed - 2001), page 88 :

> [A formula] $\varphi$ is *valid* iff for every $\mathfrak A$ and every $s : Var \to |\mathfrak A|$, $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $\varphi$ with $s$.

In turn, $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $\exists x \alpha$ with $s$ iff for some $d \in |\mathfrak A|, \vDash_\mathfrak A \alpha[s(x|d)]$.

Now, for $\exists x (¬P(x) \lor ∀yP(y))$, we have that it is valid if for any $|\mathfrak A|$ and any $s$ :

> $\vDash_\mathfrak A (¬P(x) \lor ∀yP(y))[s(x|d)]$, for some $d \in |\mathfrak A|$.

Now the conlcusion is straightforward; for any *structure* $\mathfrak A$, we have two psoobilities :

*(i)* there is some object in the domain such that the interpretation of $P$ does not hold of it, i.e. for some $d \in |\mathfrak A|$, $d \notin P^\mathfrak A$, in which case this object is the needed $d$ for $s(x|d)$ satisfying the formula;

otehrwise :

*(ii)* $P$ holds of all objects in the domain, i.e. for no $e \in |\mathfrak A|$, $e \notin P^\mathfrak A$, that means : for all $e \in |\mathfrak A|$, $e \in P^\mathfrak A$; in this case we have that for every $e \in |\mathfrak A|$, we have $\vDash_\mathfrak A P(y)[s(x|e)]$, and this means that $\vDash_\mathfrak A \forall y P(y)[s]$.

In both cases, the formula is satisfied for any *structure* $\mathfrak A$ and for any $s$, i.e. it is *valid*.

---

Alternatively, we can easily prove :

> $\vdash \exists x (P(x) \to ∀yP(y))$

using formula Q3a of **Exercise 8**, page 130 : $\vdash (∀xβ → α) ↔ ∃x(β → α)$, provided that $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

But then, in order to conlcude with the *validity* of the formula, we need the **Soundness Theorem** [page 131].

---

---

A more "formal" proof of the inconsistency of the above formula can be produced with Enderton's proof system :

1) $∀x¬(P(x) → ∀yP(y))$ --- premise

2) $¬(P(x) → ∀yP(y))$ --- from 1) and Ax.2 by *modus ponens*

3) $P(x) \land \lnot ∀yP(y)$ --- from 2) by *tautological equivalence* : $\lnot (p \to q) \leftrightarrow (p \land \lnot q)$

4) $\lnot ∀yP(y)$ --- from 3) by *tautological implication* : $p \land q \to p$

5) $P(x)$ --- from 3) as above

6) $\forall y P(y)$ --- from 5) by **Generalization Th** : $x$ is not free in 1); 4) and 6) are the desired contradiction.

Comment: Doesn't the first approach implicitly use the completeness theorem?

Comment: I think the second approach is correct thought, thank you!